# Logic of all() method for sets

Tags: python, set, boolean

The all() method returns True if all elements in a set are true. What's the logic behind the following contradictory results:

Result 1:

```
D = {'0', '000', ''}    
all(D)

#output: 
False
```

Result 2:

```
for e in D:    
    print(all(e))

#output:
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 4):

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) are clear here:

> **all(iterable)**
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

In the second case you are basically asking:

```
all('')
```

which is an empty iterable so it is `True`.

In the first case you are asking if *each* item in the set is boolean True, and the empty string is [*not* truthy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). It basically comes down to:

```
all('') != bool('')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see the empty string is interpreted as false

```
D = {'0', '000', 'x'}    
print(all(D))
```

```
True
```

vs

```
D = {'0', '000', ''}    
print(all(D))
```

```
False
```